# `section` is reset upon changing a chapter?

Tags: numbering, amsthm, latex-base

The `amsthm` documentation states:

> If any theorem elements are numbered by section, and (in a book) the first such element in a chapter comes before the first section, numbering will continue from the previous chapter. In such a case, reset the counter by invoking this command before the affected element:
>
> `\setcounter{thm}{0}`

However, I run the following MWE

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Elio}
        
    \begin{dfn}
        content
    \end{dfn}
        
        \section{Bach}
        
        \begin{dfn}
            content
        \end{dfn}
        
        
    \chapter{Oliver}
    
    \begin{dfn}
        content
    \end{dfn}
    
\end{document}
```

and find that `dfn` in the second chapter *is* correctly numbered as 2.0.1 despite not using `\setcounter{dfn}{0}`.

What is going on here?

Comment: The book class defines the section counter to be within chapter, `\newcounter{section}[chapter]` ([l. 271 of book.cls](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/texmf/tex/latex/base/book.cls#L271)). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Your instruction `\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]` overrides the default for the `book` document class, which (in essence) is `\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]`. Since a `\chapter` directive resets the `section` counter to 0, it should come as no surprise that the first `dfn` environment is numbered `2.0.1`.

Comment: @Mico then before 2015 it would have been a surprise that you wouldn't have got that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - My memory of pre-2015 settings is rather hazy...

Comment: @Mico 1993 seems like yesterday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The AMS documentation is not taking in to account a 2015 improvement in `\stepcounter`

the latex format sources (ltcounts.dtx) say:

```
% \changes{v1.1h}{2015/01/10}{Reset all within counters in one go (latexrelease)}
%
%    Rather than resetting the ``within'' counter to zero we set it to
%    $-1$ and then run |\stepcounter| that moves it to $0$ and also
%    initiates resetting the next level down.
```

It now correctly resets nested counters even if one level is "omitted"  the "initiates resetting the next level down." is the new feature added at that time.